# How to Insert image to word template using C#/JavaScript in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm-2016

Need to insert image to word template (added placeholder into template) while generating word from header button. [on click of header word template we are creating the word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGAs.png)

I am working Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 (On-Premise).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does server have Microsoft Office Installed? You need a word license which is usually not found on a server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jdweng Yes server has Microsoft office installed.

Comment: See : https://sank8sinha.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/all-about-using-plugin-in-mscrm/